# Setting PermissionModes in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Hi I working on a simple application using Azure CosmosDB. Now I want to use resource tokens to provide specific access to documents and collection in the DB. In the permission modes there are PermissionMode.Read and PermisssionMode.All. So I am assuming that PermissionMode.All allows the users to read, write, delete and post. If what I am assuming is correct, I specifically do not want my users to delete or post in a certain collection. How do I achieve this?
For better understanding, my database contains a container called users, which contains user information along with their posts and likes per post and stuff. Now I allow all my users to read (view posts of other users) and write (give a like or increment the like field), but I want to allow Post and Delete to a document to only the user of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finest granularity for assigning permissions is a partition key value so the only way to grant per document permissions is if your document id is also the partition key. If your partition key is userId and the user profile and posts, etc. all share that same partition key then that should work for you. Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#code-sample-to-create-permission) that creates a permission on a partition key for a user.

Comment: Sir, please correct me if I am wrong. As you said if I assign permission in the partition key level, provided that the partition key is also the document ID, the user has read and write access to his own documents and not of others. But I want my user to read documents of other users and also write to it but not have the power to delete or post anything to those other documents. I'm guessing this is possible. But I cant seem to find any resource that exactly does this.

Comment: There are only two permissions you can set, All (user has full permissions) or Read (The user can only read the contents of the resource but cannot perform write, update, or delete operations on the resource). There is no "Read/Write". If you want more fine grained permissions you will have to wait until late summer or fall this year when RBAC on data plane becomes available.